# Connecting HDFS on AWS EMR from local machine over java code

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, emr

I am trying to understand as how to connect from my local machine to hdfs(on aws EMR)

My sample program

```
public class EMRConnection {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
     FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://***-**-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:50070"), config);
     hdfs.mkdirs(new Path("/user/test/"));

}
```

}

i have verified and given permission to EMR to accept connection from my ip. i am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "{xyz}"; destination host is: "ec2-(xyz...).amazonaws.com":50070; 
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:467)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2394)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:817)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:813)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:813)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:806)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1933)
at EMRConnection.main(EMRConnection.java:16)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidEndTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:94)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.checkLastTagWas(CodedInputStream.java:124)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:202)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:891)
```

could somebody please let me know how should i connect ?. am i using the wrong IP or port ?

I found that port should be 8020. after this i can create folder however when i attempt to write a file 
it is throwing below exception

```
could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Comment: EMR connection is now working however if i attemp to write a file it says

Answer (score 0):

When i have used port as 8020. it worked.Sharing as other might will face same.